# Using PHP eval to run code causes Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function

Tags: php, eval

I have a PHP script that selects one of many PHP code snippets from the database and executes it using eval. In some cases if two code snippets try to declare a function with the same name, I get the fatal error "cannot redeclare function". Editing the function names in the code snippets is not an option. Is there some way to create a scope or maybe have the functions overwrite each other? Or any other better ideas?

Thanks.

Edit: Loops this code.

```
ob_start();
try {
    $result = eval($source_code);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "error";
}
$error = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: can we see what you were actually trying to do?

Comment: @DevDonkey I can see the code perfectly fine! Are you not psychic or something? Get with it :-)

Comment: If you post some code we might be able to help, otherwise short of renaming a function or moving it into a class you're probably out of luck.  You could also use `function_exists`

Comment: Hands off from eval!

Comment: @DevDonkey There you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three choices, really.

## [function_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php)

```
// this will check for the function's existence before trying to declare it
if(!function_exists('cool_func')){
    function cool_func(){
        echo 'hi';
    }
}

// business as usual
cool_func();
```

## Assign function to a variable

```
// this will automatically overwrite any uses of $cool_func within the current scope
$cool_func = function(){
    echo 'hi';
}

// call it like this
$cool_func();
```

## [Namespacing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php) in PHP >= 5.3.0

```
/* WARNING: this does not work */
/* eval() operates in the global space */
namespace first {
    eval($source_code);
    cool_func();
}

namespace second {
    eval($source_code);
    cool_func();
}

// like this too
first\cool_func();
second\cool_func();

/* this does work */
namespace first {
    function cool_func(){echo 'hi';}
    cool_func();
}

namespace second {
    function cool_func(){echo 'bye';}
    cool_func();
}
```

---

With the second example you would need to `eval()` the DB code once within every scope which you need to use `$cool_func`, see below:

```
eval($source_code);

class some_class{
    public function __construct(){
        $cool_func(); // <- produces error
    }
}

$some_class = new some_class(); // error shown

class another_class{
    public function __construct(){
        eval($source_code); // somehow get DB source code in here :)
        $cool_func(); // works
    }
}

$another_class = new another_class(); // good to go
```

Comment: There are 1000s of code snippets. There is no way to edit every single one. Also even if the functions have the same name doesn't mean that they do the same thing so I can't use !function_exists

Comment: But don't all of those solution require editing the code snippets in the database?

Comment: @user4712608 No, not the namespacing one; you will just need to update how your PHP code calls the function which was `eval()`'d from the DB. I added a fourth option btw

Comment: to call the functions with the namespace I need to include the namespace before the function name. Since the functions are being created and called inside the code snippets, it would require me to edit the code snippets.

Comment: @user4712608 see my edit again. Also I could not get option 4 to work in my testing so NVM about the class option.

Comment: @user4712608 hire a programmer, then.

Comment: @user4712608 It looks like the namespacing example is not working as expected because the `eval()` seems to operate in the global scope and `cool_func()` fails to redeclare. I am all out of ideas... Thanks you for showing me that putting PHP code in the DB is fraught with peril :-/

Comment: I made it work. I used `include()` instead of `eval()`. I just create a temporary file of the PHP code wrapped in a unique namespace.

Comment: @user4712608 Nice! Your dilemma actually caused me to dive deeper into namespaces and if you want to avoid creating a temporary file on disk (disk has the slowest access time) then I recommend checking out the `include` section of the person that answered my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945327/namespacing-with-eval-and-include-does-not-work-as-expected but you'll have to make sure that `allow_url_fopen = On` and `allow_url_include = On` in your `php.ini` file. If you want to switch back to `eval()` then that is covered as well in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as mentioned by others, you should post the code so we can better help you. But you may want to look into PHP OOP as you can give scope to methods within classes and reference them as such:

```
ClassOne::myFunction();
ClassTwo::myFunction();
```

See this for more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: There are 1000s of code snippets. I cannot edit every single one. It would take months.

Comment: Then I guess you're screwed because you cannot declare two functions with the same name to run in the same scope in PHP. If you don't want to edit any code, how exactly did you expect to solve the problem?